# How does the JE instruction work without CMP?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

```
.L10:
    leal    (%rsi,%rsi,4), %edx
    movsbl  %al,%eax
    addq    $1, %rdi
    leal    -48(%rax,%rdx,2), %esi
    je  .L3
```

In the above there's no `cmp` preceding `je`. How does it work here?

Comment: That's not all the code, keep on looking back to `L3`.

Comment: no need looking back, `addq` is the last instruction which updates the flag.

Comment: For assembly questions you should always specify which architecture you're using.

Comment: @Tom Zych Added the tag. The code in this question makes it rather obvious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- `je` will jump is `ZF = 1`.
- `add` modifies the `ZF`.
- `lea`, `movsb` does not affect any flags.

Keep the [Intel 64 and IA32 Architecture Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html/) in hand. You can find all the instruction details of Intel 64 and IA32 architecture in the [manual Volume 2](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2a-2b-instruction-set-a-z-manual.html)

Comment: When does add set ZF flag to 1?

Comment: when the result of the addition becomes 0, ZF becomes 1

Comment: So you mean when `%rdi` is `-1`?

Comment: Yes, which means if `rdi` is `0` then it will jump to `.L3` .

Comment: i have corrected the above comment. When `rdi` is `-1`, `1` is added and `rdi` becomes zero, which makes `ZF=1`, and the next `je` will make the jump. Therefore when `rdi` is zero the jump will be made.

Answer (score 5):

`je` jumps if the ZF flag is set in the EFLAGS register. The value of the ZF flag is set by the previous (for example `cmp`) operation that modified it.

Since neither `lea` nor `movsbl` modify the ZF flag, but `add` does (compare [Intel Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2a-2b-instruction-set-a-z-manual.html), 3-36), `je` jumps to `.L3` iff `$1 + %rdi` is zero.

Comment: $1 + %rdi is zero, => %rdi is -1?

Answer (score 1):

The preceding instruction sets a processor status flag. Each conditional jump checks a certain flag, even if a `cmp` was not executed. I believe `je` executes if the zero flag is set.